# Is it possible to have a nested CSS so that all rules in it apply only to children of a certain element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know I could write:

```
#parentElement h1 {
    /*rules*/
}

#parentElement div {
    /*rules*/
}
```

etc etc

but if I had an extremely long list of such rules, it would be incredibly convenient to have a syntax where I could write something along the lines of:

```
#parentElement {
    h1 {
        /*rules*/
    }

    div {
        /*rules*/
    }
}
```

Like a media query.

Does anything like this exist? I couldn't find anything on Google but it seemed like such an obvious idea that it had it exist in some fashion.

Comment: Look into scss and less: http://sass-lang.com/ and http://lesscss.org/

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/guide After writing the scss (or sass or less) code you will need to compile it to a .css file

Comment: Thanks, I'd heard about sass but never tried it since we don't use it at work.

Comment: Use prepros if you want to make it more easy in development. Advantages is auto-compiling templating engines. Live preview. Unlimited Free Trial. You can buy it if you have a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

Consider formatting your styles in a visually assistive manner:

```
.PARENT-ELEMENT-STYLES,

    .parentElement h1 {
        /*rules*/
    }

    .parentElement div {
        /*rules*/
    }


/*****************/
/*****************/


.CHILD-ELEMENT-STYLES,

    .childElement h1 {
        /*rules*/
    }

    .childElement div {
        /*rules*/
    }
```